# Android alarm manager doesn't trigger my event

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm having some trouble adding notifications to my app. I would like a notification everyday at 10am, for example. Here's my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setAlarm();
}

private void setAlarm() {
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 3, alarmIntent);
}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.turnu_a.todolist">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".taskView.newTaskActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".taskView.showTaskDetailsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".taskView.updateTaskActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".settings.settingsActivity"></activity>
    <receiver android:name=".Alarm.AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
</application>
```

The thing is, even though I change the time for the trigger to happen in a minute or two (in order to test my code), absolutely nothing happens. I've tried to create a notification in the "setAlarm()" method and it worked, meaning the problem doesn't come from the creation of the notification but the alarmManager not being triggered.
I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: AlarmManager does not support intervals of 3 seconds like you currently have it set (1000*3).  Have you checked the alarm info in the terminal using `adb she'll dumpsys alarm`?  It should show how the alarm is being set.. might be setting it for the next day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I removed this line:

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

from the "setAlarm()" method and now it works.

I am glad it works but a bit surprised the problem came from here (though in hindsight, I don't think this line is quite useful anyway).

Anyway, problem solved, thanks to everyone who tried to help.